# What is going on with NPM?

Tags: npm

I ran `npm audit fix --force` and I noticed this `npm WARN deprecated acorn-dynamic-import@3.0.0: This is probably built in to whatever tool you're using. If you still need it... idk`.

Is this normal or usual thing that NPM does?

Comment: NPM just conveys whatever message the maintainer provided, you can see the same text on https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn-dynamic-import. But you generally shouldn't `npm audit fix --force` as that can introduce breaking changes into your dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit [npm for this package](https://npmjs.com/acorn-dynamic-import) you'll see the same deprecation message the author has added.

The author is no longer recommending use of this package, as the functionality is now probably part of any runtime like NodeJS. In this case newer versions of `acron` support this feature without a plugin.

You can probably ignore this message, as the package is probably a dependency of another package you installed. Make sure to update said package and possibly inform the authors of that package (who this message is meant for).